# Динамическое подключение jar библиотеки в android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, библиотеки, jar

Мне нужно подключить динамично библиотеку dyn.jar из папки "libs", но я не понимаю, как это сделать. Пробовал DexClassLoader, но у меня не работало, выдавало, что путь неверный, а я не знаю, какой тут путь писать до файла, именно который находится в папке проекта на компе, а не в самом телефоне.

```
String jarPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/dyn.jar";

final DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(jarPath, getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

try {
    classLoader.loadClass("com.example.dyn.ExtendedCalculations");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Может надо указать не путь к внутреннему каталогу приложения, а путь к папке с библиотеками?

```java
String jarPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "libs/dyn.jar";

final DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(jarPath, getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

try {
    classLoader.loadClass("com.example.dyn.ExtendedCalculations");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Все равно не работает и выдает вот такое

`W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.example.calculator/files/libs/dyn.jar
W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.dyn.ExtendedCalculations" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /prets/lib64]]
`